# Confirm to you vs confirm you

Tags: difference

Which one is correct?
You is the indirect object here. We usually use indirect object after verb (without  preposition) when we use the direct object after indirect object or when we don't use direct object in a sentence.

**E.g,**

"Give me your pencil." (Me is the indirect object and pencil is the direct object.)

**So what should I say?**

> 1) I will confirm you tomorrow.
>
> Or
>
> 2) I will confirm that to you tomorrow.

I think both are correct.
I hope so you will understand what I said.

Comment: They're different. If you have a substance or material that conforms to someone, that's different from conforming someone to something else. Both are completely different from *confirming* anything.

Comment: I think you mean _confirm_. If you are going to tell someone tomorrow that some information they have is indeed correct, you will _confirm it to them_. As @Lawrence says, _conform_ is a completely different word.

Comment: When you say *conform you* do you mean it in the sense of *follow your instructions* or *do as you say*? As in *I will give you my pencil tomorrow*? (To be clear, nobody ever says either version of your sentence, and it's so strange that your intended meaning isn't known.)